# THREE JS: GPM Process Memory leak

Tags: memory, three.js, gpu

I am creating a web app using THREE JS which contains multiple 3D view.
Here is the code flow.

1. Created scene.
2. Created camera and added to the scene
3. Added light to the scene.
4. Added WebGLRenderer.
5. Added 3D objects to the scene.
6. Removed objects added in step 3 and added 3D objects of some other view.

On repeating steps 5 and 6 several times, GPU memory shoots up and browser becomes unresponsive.

Comment: See https://threejs.org/examples/?q=memory. Type `renderer.info` into the console.

Comment: Ive reread this a few times and still dont understand it. Why are you removing the light every time you add new objects? What does `and added 3D objects of some other view.` mean?

Comment: I am not removing light. Only visible 3D objects are added and removed.

Answer (score 0):

In order to clean memory in three.js. You need to call dispose function for geometry, material and texture explicitly. Here is the explanation from threejs. Hope this helps.

https://threejs.org/docs/#manual/en/introduction/How-to-dispose-of-objects

Comment: @Arif Shaikh Is this solving your problem?